# Javascript display based on Date

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that already has a call to an SQL database, and I want to display a div based on a condition on one of the entries. I can't quite get this to work for me though, and I'm struggling to find the right answer. 
I want a Div called `#expiryDate` to display with JavaScript if the expiry date column entry on the database, is a month away.

I can display the db entry with `<?php echo $data["expires"]; ?>`
But I want to do something like this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $function() {
    var subval;
    subval = $data["expires"];

    if(..........) {
      $('#expiryDate').show();
    } else {
      $('#expiryDate').hide();
    }
  }};
</script>
```

But I can't work out the if bit. I want it to be
If the date in `$date["expires"]` is a month away then....
What am I missing?

Comment: `if (is_a_month_away(subval)) { ...`?

Comment: You need to do some math with `subval` and the current date. What is the format of `subval` and what does php have to do with it?

Comment: I used php to echo the data from the table, which I tried having in the js function. The date format is 2014-10-17 as it appears in the sql table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lts1rg18/

Assuming `$data["expires"]` is a date string;

```
 var expDate = new Date(<?php echo "$data['expires']"; ?>);
 var now = new Date();
 var oneMonthFromNow = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate());

 if(expDate <= oneMonthFromNow) {
   $('#expiryDate').show();
 } else {
   $('#expiryDate').hide();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Yes it is a date string on the database. My own user expiry date is 2016 so, for this test, the #expiryDate div shouldn't appear. Do I wrap this in a $(function)? I've tried both..

Comment: Yes you should wrap it in page load function

Comment: It's not happening for me... I've got it all in the js script tags, in between $(function(){.... });. It shouldn't matter where it sits on the page should it? The <div> elements are further up but that doesn't matter does it?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle-demo to my answer

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that works. Just need to work it with the $data["expires"] bit which it doesn't appear to. Thanks for doing that though. Very useful

Comment: I've added the php echo to the var expDate line which I omitted earlier. That has allowed it to work now. In case someone else comes here wanting to do the same thing. Thanks for the help with this sebbzzz.

Comment: @actionjack you can make suggestions, but let the responder correct their own answer... i agree with you, by the way, the php variable should be echoed...

Comment: @actionjack just realized you are the OP: give it another thought if it's actually the correct answer or not, considering the formatting is definitely not correct...

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using .NET lately and was a bit rusty on the PHP. I edited the answer to include the echo

Answer (score 1):

If possible, perform the calculations within PHP to avoid putting pressure on the clients browser.

I like Sebbzzz answer but, personal preference sees my time calculations happen in timestamps so:

```
<?php
$strExpiryTimestamp = strtotime($date["expires"]);

/* For mockup purposes */
$intMonth = 1; /* date('n') Gets this month */
$intYear = 2014; /* date('Y') Gets this year */
$intStartOfMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $intMonth, 1, $intYear);

if($strExpiryTimestamp < $intStartOfMonth) {
    $strOp = 'show';
} else {
    $strOp = 'hide';
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Your HTML</h1>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#expiryDate').<?php echo $strOp; ?>();
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the above approach, you can clearly see that the calculations are performed "on top" at the server and then the script part can be included wherever you please so long as $strOp is available as a variable.

If you want to find out some more information on date, check out the PHP manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Should this wrap around the <div> coding with the else{  } surrounding nothing if I don't want it to display? Thanks

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include for you one way of performing with the JS

Comment: Right, that seems to be working... hurrah! It didn't when I moved the code to the bottom of the page though, it only works when it sits above the <div id="expiryDate" code. By the way, its $data["expires"]. Is there no way it could be done by exact month though?

Comment: I've added some code which factors in exact months/years for you

Comment: As written, the math will cause the expiryDate element to always show except for when the expiration date is more than 1 month in the future.

Comment: The intMonth/Year etc bits stop the page from loading. Is there something missing from them? Thanks

Comment: i see it. remove the second bracket at the end of the $intStartOfMonth line, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to your project and try something like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    expiryDate();
});

function expiryDate() {
    var dbDate = $data["expires"];
    var expDate = moment(dbDate).format();
    var curDate = moment().format();
    var oneb4 = moment(expDate).subtract(1, 'months').format();

    if (curDate > oneb4) {
        $('#expiryDate').show();
    } else {
        $('#expiryDate').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may well try that if I can't get the other suggestions working. Thanks